# drop down menu html

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

```
<select>
      <option value="">Select an Option</option>
      <option value="one">Option 1</option>
      <option value="two">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

For every option tag I am attaching one value by value attribute, How can I attach one more variable to hold some value for option tag?

Comment: Do you want to attach one more variable in php or what? explain it clearly

Comment: can you explain why you need it? you can concatenate value by any character e.g value="one#two", then split the value by "#", and you will get array.

Comment: the value attribute can have value which might have '#' as char or any special char.

Comment: you can use id <option value="one"  id="">.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<select>
  <option value="">Select an Option</option>
  <option rel="othervalue1" value="one">Option 1</option>
  <option rel="othervalue2" value="two">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by adding more option value?

```
enter code here
<select>
<option value="">Select an Option</option>
<option value="one">Option 1</option>
<option value="two">Option 2</option>
<option value="three">Option 3</option>
<option value="four">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Just add more?

Answer (score 0):

try this
add one more attribute what ever  name you need

```
<select>
      <option value="" value2="">Select an Option</option>
      <option value="one"  value2="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="two"  value2="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can only hav one value per option. But you can enter more than one word in the value. If you have a lot of information, you can use for exampel JSON. Just make sure that you escape "

in PHP you can easy extract the JSON with http://de3.php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php